# User deletes all notification from status bar, how to get the event

Tags: android, notifications

In my application I create a notification and delete it when the user clicks on it, and it works without problems. However the user can delete the notification also by pressing the key on the status bar that clears all notifications, how can I listen for this event to better manage notifications in my database?

EDIT: thanks to Zielony, to complete the answer is necessary to register a BroadcastReceiver for the action `notification_cancelled` and add `.setDeleteIntent(PendentIntent())` to Notification.Builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace clicking with a deleteIntent action.

[deleteIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#deleteIntent)